# How to create gifs with images in Python

Tags: python

Are there any APIs or libraries I can use to create a .gif out of .jpgs and .pngs? I'm looking for one that will work with Python 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is something that I wrote a while ago.  I couldn't find anything better when I wrote this in the last six months.  Hopefully this can get you started.  It uses ImageMagick found [here!](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

```
import os, sys
import glob
dataDir = 'directory of image files' #must contain only image files
#change directory gif directory
os.chdir(dataDir)


#Create txt file for gif command
fileList = glob.glob('*') #star grabs everything, can change to *.png for only png files
fileList.sort()
#writes txt file
file = open('blob_fileList.txt', 'w')
for item in fileList:
    file.write("%s\n" % item)

file.close()


#verifies correct convert command is being used, then converts gif and png to new gif
os.system('SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion')
os.system('SET IMCONV="C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16\Convert"')
# The following line is where you can set delay of images (100)
os.system('%IMCONV% -delay 100 @fileList.txt theblob.gif')
```

**New convert call**

For whatever reason (I didn't look at differences), I no longer needed the set local and set command lines in the code.  I needed it before because the convert command was not being used even with path set.  When you use the new 7.*.* release of image magick.  See new line of code to replace last three lines.  **Be sure to check box that ask to download legacy commands e.g convert when installing**.  Everything was converted to a single magick command, but I didnt want to relearn the new conventions.

```
os.system('convert -delay 50 @fileList.txt animated.gif')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try googling, there are a lot of answers for this question. Here are the top three when I looked

[Programmatically generate video or animated GIF in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753190/programmatically-generate-video-or-animated-gif-in-python)

[Generating an animated GIF in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041893/generating-an-animated-gif-in-python)

https://sukhbinder.wordpress.com/2014/03/19/gif-animation-in-python-in-3-steps/