# django create gif and store in DB

Tags: python, django, sqlite, gif

I'm receiving files from an input via a POST request. I'd like to take to those create a GIF from them and store it directly in a sqlite database.

I have found various ways in python to create GIFs out of images and save them to the file system like the one here

```
VALID_EXTENSIONS = ('png', 'jpg')

def createGIF(data, duration=0.2):
    images = []
    for d in data:
        images.append(imageio.imread(d))
    output_file = 'Gif-%s.gif' % datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%M-%d-%H-%M-%S')
    imageio.mimsave(output_file, images, duration=duration)
```

but I was not able to find a way of creating the GIF and either store it into variable or save it into the DB directly. 
Is there any way of creating a GIF and not have to save it to disk first before putting it in a DB?

Answer (score 0):

> Storing files in a database should never happen. If it’s being
>   considered as a solution for a problem, find a certified  database
>   expert and ask for a second opinion.

From: [Two Scopes of Django](https://www.twoscoopspress.com/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-8)

As [coderanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5142559/coderanger) suggested, use a [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField) or [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#imagefield) instead.

Answer (score -1):

For creating GIF's, You can look at this answer: [How to create gifs with images in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38444619/how-to-create-gifs-with-images-in-python).

And for saving it, you will need [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ImageField).

Comment: I know how to create an GIF in python as my example shows; what I was not able to figure out is how to create a GIF and store it directly in a database (or alternatively store it in a variable) and not having to save it to the file system at all

Comment: You have to save it somewhere.